# Combining a SVG chart with an HTML UI element

Tags: jquery, html, svg, d3.js

I would like to build a chart with SVG (using D3, Chartist, or any other library that comes in handy) as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there is a button in the lower right hand corner, and it should enable a searchable dropdown menu as follows:

[image]

I know of `foreignObject`, but I need to have >= IE9 support, and I would like to stay away from any nasty hacks, i.e. code the interactive element in plain HTML & JS.

What would be the easiest way to implement such a thing? I am looking for general directions, not concrete code examples (but those are welcome too, of course). One idea I came up with is just absolutely positioning the state-triggering button (and the whole interactive element) over the SVG element, but I don't even know if that is possible, i.e., if keyboard and mouse events are captured.

Comment: Build it in html to get dropdowns and scrollbars and add SVG as content.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.. of course the page will be written in HTML.

Comment: It seemed from your mention of foreignObject that you were considering writing it in SVG and then adding html elements via foreignObject.